# Compile subdir-objects multiple times

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

Automake 1.14 is causing us a few issues. At first, automake errored with the complaint:

> warning: source file 'X' is in a subdirectory but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled

So I enabled subdir-objects, but now it isn't recompiling some files. For example, lets say

`src/a/foo.c` is compiled in SUBDIR `a` but in `src/b`, I would like to compile it again with different preprocessor flags, however since `../a/foo.o` already exists, make doesn't rebuild it. This is because subdir-objects changes `am_b_OBJECTS` to look for `../a/foo.o` instead of `foo.o`. Is there a way I can get around the original complaint and instruct make to build the file a second time with the appropriate preprocessor flags? This all worked on previous versions of automake.

I would settle for executing `rm ../a/foo.o` before compiling src/b but I don't know how to edit the Makefile.am to make that happen.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you're using `subdir-objects` under the same tree from different `Makefile.am` files. As automake can't see you're using the same source file with different parameters it'll assume it was rebuilt correctly.

The proper solution to this is to not use separate `Makefile.am` files and instead rephrase the build system as [non-recursive automake](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html) and so in that case it would then build `foo.c` as `foo-a.o` and `foo-b.o`.